# Print all the elements meeting a condition JSON

Tags: json, python-2.7, loops

Having a json like this one:

```
json = {'example1': 0, 'example2': 16, 'example3': 12}
```

Is it possible to print only the ones who are greater than 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
>>> json = {'example1': 0, 'example2': 16, 'example3': 12}
>>> print(*[k for k in json if json[k] > 10])
example2 example3
```

The idea here is to use a list comprehension that iterates over the keys of the dictionary and filters those for which the value is greater than 10.

The filtered items are then unpacked for printing by `print()`.